# Solve coupled differential equation using the function scipy.integrate.RK45

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x' = f(x,y,t)
y' = g(x,y,t)
```

Initial conditions have been given as x0 and y0 with t0. Find the solution graph in the range t0 to a.

I have tried doing this for non-coupled equations but there seems to be a problem there as well. I have to solve this exactly using this function so other functions are not the options.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def f(t,x):
    return -x
import scipy
from scipy import integrate as inte

solution = inte.RK45(f, 0 , [1] , 10 ,1, 0.001, e**-6)
print (solution)
```

I expect the output to be an array of all the values.

But `<scipy.integrate._ivp.rk.RK45 at 0x1988ba806d8>` is what I get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to collect data by calling the integrator `step()` method:

```
from math import e
from scipy import integrate as inte


def f(t,x):
    return -x


solution = inte.RK45(f, 0 , [1] , 10 ,1, 0.001, e**-6)

# collect data
t_values = []
y_values = []
for i in range(100):
    # get solution step state
    solution.step()
    t_values.append(solution.t)
    y_values.append(solution.y[0])
    # break loop after modeling is finished
    if solution.status == 'finished':
        break

data = zip(t_values, y_values)
```

Output:

```
(0.12831714796342164, 0.879574381033538)
(1.1283171479634215, 0.3239765636806864)
(2.1283171479634215, 0.11933136762238628)
(3.1283171479634215, 0.043953720407578944)
(4.128317147963422, 0.01618962035012491)
(5.128317147963422, 0.005963176828962677)
(6.128317147963422, 0.002196436798667919)
(7.128317147963422, 0.0008090208875093502)
(8.128317147963422, 0.00029798936023261037)
(9.128317147963422, 0.0001097594143523445)
(10, 4.5927433621121034e-05)
```

Comment: But this will be giving me only integer values between 0 and 100 for t. I think this program is to provide me adjusted step size for t, which is my main aim. I need the values of y where the equation is stiff. Am I missing something or else?

Comment: I also need some help with a program that uses the adaptive step size method in Runge Kutta algorithm. All of them I find are in Matlab. There are some in scipy, but I don't know how to give the input when I have more than two coupled equations and at times of higher order. Can anyone help?

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed. I would like to ask how you would sweep all the data in the loop (something like: len (solution)) instead of placing range (100) (since the step is variable, it is not known a priori how much data we will have)? Thank you.